# package.json dependency alternative source

Tags: node.js, package, npm

Can you tell that specific dependency would be cloned from a different source not npmjs?
Something maybe like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "foo": 
     { 
       "ver":">= 2.0"
       "src":"https://github.com/foo/foo.git"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you want is on the Github or a valid git address, you can

"dependencies": {
        "express": "visionmedia/express"
    }

or

"dependencies": {
        "express": "git://github.com/visionmedia/express.git#commit-ish"
    }

where the `#commit-ish` is the commit hash ID which will helps you to specify version number.

Take a look on Official guides: https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies, you can do more than you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can define github dependency like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "foo": "username/foo"
}
```

It's not possible to specify semver ranges for github packages yet. If you need that, you can use [yapm](https://github.com/rlidwka/yapm) instead, and write syntax like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "foo": "username/foo@>=2"
}
```